# Find max and min of y coordinate of 3D numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, min

I am a complete beginner in Python and am trying to use it to generate a merged data file to be used in a molecular simulation.

I am trying to place one group of atoms over the other along the y-axis using the ASE python code. For this I need to find the minimum of y coordinate of one atom group stored as a 3D numpy array (atoms_1) and maximum of y coordinate of the second atom group stored as a 3D numpy array (atoms_2). Which is the best method to do this?

I have tried:

```
y_min = np.max([atoms_2[:,1]])

y_max = np.min([atoms_1[:,1]])
```

Not sure if the syntax is correct. Any help or tips appreciated.

Comment: I think `np.amax` might be what you're looking for https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html

Comment: @Nathan `np.max` is an alias for `np.amax`

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing seems correct. You can remove the brackets as well:

```
y_min = np.max(atoms_2[:,1])

y_max = np.min(atoms_1[:,1])
```

`np.max` is an alias for `np.amax` suggested in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum value in each of the columns using:

```
import numpy as np

atoms = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9],
                  [1, 4, 6]])

print(np.amax(atoms, axis=0))

>>> [7 8 9]
print(np.amin(atoms, axis=0))
>>> [1 2 3]
```

To assign it, just use:

```
x_max, y_max, z_max = np.amax(atoms, axis=0)
x_min, y_min, z_min = np.amin(atoms, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass axis into `max` and `min`

```
a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,-1)

a.max(axis=1), a.min(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
(array([[ 6,  7,  8],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [24, 25, 26]]),
 array([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [18, 19, 20]]))
```